# Помогите разобраться с Docker (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, pgadmin

Сразу скажу: с докером подружился недавно, и я пока с ним на **ВЫ**

Скачал и установил официальный образ с https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres
Запустил с пробросом портов

```
docker run --name dbserver -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d postgrest/postgrest
```

Пытаюсь подключиться через pgAdmin

Но подключиться из pgAdmin всё равно не могу. В чём проблема?

[image: Enable to connect]

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете не тот образ, нужен [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres). Вы же запускаете веб приложение (REST api для postgres), которое стартует на порту 3000 ([GitHub](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest), [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/postgrest/postgrest)).

Попробуйте:

```
docker run --name dbserver -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d postgres
```

А вообще, проверить что происхотит с приложением можно:

Отобразит все контейнеры и можно посмотреть запущен он или крешнулся:

```
docker ps -a
```

Логи, в них приложения часто пишут, что происхотит:

```
docker logs <container_name_or_id>
```

Ещё для БД в контейнере обычно делают mount volume или bind ([Docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)), чтобы при кажном перезапуске/удалении контейнера не терять данные.

Comment: Не скачивается. Пишет таймаут...